# return to the first frame opened in wpf xaml with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame, back

I am creating WPF application that proceeds in several upper frame with different data displayed for each open frame , reloaded passing an id .

If I want to go back one frame I can use this :

```
this.NavigationService.GoBack();
```

But , question , if I wanted to return to the first frame , without necessarily charging everyone I've opened in sequence, you can ?
type a method:

> this.NavigationService.GoFirstFrameOpen ()

There is a similar function ? And if not, a possible solution ?

Comment: Do you want the history to reflect that you went back, or that you navigated forward to the first page?  That is, do you want go forward to take you to the second page after you go back to the first?  If so I think you'll have to go back through all of them.  If not you could keep a reference to the first page and just navigate to that.

Comment: I would not go back doing all the frames , I would go back to the first that the user opens. is possible ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer Is your problem solved ? If yes, plz mark correct answer, if not, tell the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Frame.BackStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.backstack(v=vs.100).aspx) property.
It returns an IEnumerable that you use to enumerate the entries in back navigation history for a Frame.

You can get the containing Frame by traversing the VisualTree.

Sample :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var leaf = (DependencyObject)sender;
    while(leaf.GetType() != typeof(Frame))
    {
        leaf = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(leaf);
    }

    Frame f = leaf as Frame;
    if (f != null)
    {
        JournalEntry firstItem = null;
        foreach (JournalEntry item in f.BackStack)
        {
            firstItem = item;
            break;
        }

        this.NavigationService.Navigate(firstItem.Source);
    }
}
```

Addional methods if you are navigating from within the Page, then

1. You can have your `Page` class have a parameterized constructor receiving the Frame object.
2. You can use a while loop with going backward until you reach the first pageentry.
3. Use a `PageFunction`. A [PageFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615540(v=vs.110).aspx)  is a Page which can return a value.

[WPF Navigation](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation)

Comment: the problem is that I am inside the frame , I can not recall this with BackStack method